# Boundedness of $ a_{n+2}=\pi(a_{n+1})+\pi(a_n)+k $

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Let $a_1,a_2,k$ be positive integers and let $\pi$ be the prime-counting function, with the convention that $\pi(1)=0$. Then, define the sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge 1}$ by the recursion
$$
a_{n+2}=\pi(a_{n+1})+\pi(a_n)+k
$$
for all $n\ge 1$. Is it true that the above sequence is bounded?

Comment: Hint: $\pi(n)\leq n/2$.

Comment: Hint for modified problem: $\pi(n)<n/3$ for large enough $n$.

Comment: If you wish to use it, sure. Using PNT an overkill, and using the inequality I mention is easier, and moreover PNT arguably doesn't fit the (elementary-number-theory) tag, but hey, whatever floats your boat, right? :)

Comment: @Wojowu You are right; I removed the comment because I realized after a moment it was an overkill (I remove also the tag, just in case one would like to use it :P)